# join inner select query with main query

Tags: mysql

I want to create a lecturers' monthly attendance report in my course management system. In this report I need to use nested select queries to count number of presence and absence of lecturers in show them in specific records.
I thought the possible way to do it is to use a select statement for each of the attendance status to be counted if the lecturer code is the same as the lecturer code being processed in the main query!

```
select lecturers.*, sum(distinct courses.credit) as 'Due Credits',(select count(*) from attendances where status='1' ) as Present, (select count(*) from attendances where status='0' ) as Absent from lecturers,courses,attendances
 where attendances.lecturer_code=lecturers.code 
 AND courses.lecturer_code=lecturers.code 
 group by lecturer_code
```

[code, Name,Department,Official Position, Degree are fixed attributes]

I need to know if there is a better way to do it!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post the tables' structures, some sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   lecturers.*,
         SUM(DISTINCT courses.credit) AS `Due Credits`,
         SUM(attendances.status = 1)  AS `Present`,
         SUM(attendances.status = 0)  AS `Absent`,
FROM     lecturers
    JOIN courses     ON     courses.lecturer_code = lecturers.code
    JOIN attendances ON attendances.lecturer_code = lecturers.code
GROUP BY lecturer_code
```